# Errors with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I am trying to implement the jobs API by facebook on my webpage and while trying to get the recruiting managers on the Graphs API get an error as below :

Request : `me/recruiting_managers`

Response :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3,
    "fbtrace_id": "Ae0HxroItowuqypeuULh2J0"
  }
}
```

I submitted the associated form thrice and sent them emails but haven't got any replies. Can anyone help me with this error, please?

[image: This is how I am trying to get it work]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not authenticated, and therefore do not have an active token, which would then be passed with this request in order to authorize it.

Comment: I have generated a new user token for the app on Graph API and still get this issue

Comment: Are you passing it to this call, and then registering/qualifying it?

Comment: I am trying to get the token as per the image attached above

Comment: I am following this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/jobs-xml/#1--generate-your-xml-feed

Nowhere does it say to use any token inside the code or am I missing something?

For now, I just generate the Access token on the Graph API.